# how to remove word by another column values in sas

Tags: sas, datastep

let's assume the data should like:

| Words | remove this word in first column |
| --- | --- |
| Michigan address 21356 | 21356 |
| Hawaii 31256 address | 31256 |
| 1235 broadway niceblock | 1235 |

Sample Data in csv format:

```
data have;
    infile datalines dlm=',';
    length words remove $50.;
    input words$ remove$;
    datalines;
Michigan address 21356,21356
Hawaii 31256 address,31256
1235 broadway niceblock,1235
;
run;
```

I have data like that. I want to remove some words in the first column based on the second column value. How can I do that?

I tried some loops operation but didn't make it. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Use `transtrn` with `compbl` and `strip` to remove any extra spaces introduced by removing values.

```
data want;
   set have;
   words = strip(compbl(transtrn(words, strip(remove), strip(' ') ) ) );
run;
```

Comment: Might want to pass the result through COMPL() to reduce the resulting double spaces to a single space.

Comment: Good idea. Added that.